# how to efficiently manage cassandra initial token?

Tags: cassandra

I'm new cassandra user. I know that there is initial token configuration and how to generate it.
The question is if I have an existen cluster with x nodes and I want to add additional node (one or more) should I reconfigure all the nodes to the new tokens (according to new  generated values)?

Or is there more efficient way to manage this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for what the best practices are for handling such tasks, take a look at this section of the Cassandra 1.0 docs dedicated to [token strategy](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/cluster_management#calculating-tokens-for-the-new-nodes).

Shortened version of your options, from the documentation:

> - **Add capacity by doubling the cluster size** -- *[..]* nodes can keep their existing token assignments, and new nodes are assigned tokens that bisect (or trisect) the existing token ranges.
> - **Recalculate new tokens for all nodes and move nodes** -- *[..]* you will have to recalculate tokens for the entire cluster. Existing nodes will have to have their new tokens assigned using nodetool move.
> - **Add one node at a time and leave initial_token empty** -- *[..]* splits the token range of the heaviest loaded node and places the new node into the ring at that position. *[..]* not result in a perfectly balanced ring, but it will alleviate hot spots.
>     link

If you were seeking a management solution [Priam (from Netflix)](https://github.com/netflix/priam) might be worth looking at. It's open source and Apache-licensed, but requires some amount of configuration and is probably only worth investing [time] in for larger clusters.